# Why is Vagrant in Ubuntu Docker container on Windows looking for PowerShell?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, docker-for-windows

I am taking some training where all of the examples are in Ubuntu, but I am on Windows.

So I thought I would install an Ubuntu Docker container, and that went well.

The examples also require VirtualBox and Vagrant to be installed in Ubuntu, so I installed those in my Ubuntu container, and again all is well.

However, when I run `vagrant up` from my Ubuntu docker container (running in a PowerShell) I am getting an error:

> Failed to locate the PowerShell executable on the available PATH. Please ensure PowerShell is installed and available on the local PATH, then run the command again.

I have installed PowerShell for Ubuntu 20.04 (my version) following the instructions here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1
The installation was successful, and I am able to launch a new PowerShell, but the same error message comes.

It seems like Vagrant in Docker Ubuntu is looking for a Windows installation. There is nothing in my Vagrant file that refers to anything about Powershell.

Is Vagrant supported in this fashion, running in an Ubuntu Docker container on Windows in PowerShell?

Comment: The StackExchange sites, SU, SO, etc... has rules we re supposed to adhere to: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask), [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: This not a PowerShell code issue, which is what we are here to help with. I've never heard of Vagrant, yet, this is an environment requirements issue on your system as per the error message. There are two implementations of PowerShell. Window PowerShell, on WInodws OS only, and PowerShell Core, which is cross-platform, Windows, Linux, and OSX. If you are on linux and Vagrant is looking for PowerShell, then you need to install [PowerShell Core (Linux install)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+core+Linux+install%27&t=h_&ia=web). So, your query can be seen as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks but super user has a vagrant topic and when I searched for the right stack overflow site to post vagrant issues I was directed here.

Comment: If this is not the right forum for this can you please suggest one. I tried your suggestion but no luck

Comment: No worries and I am sure SU has a Vagrant topic, but this is the PowerShell topic. I am sure that the reason you got directed here was that you added the Powershell tag and did not provide PowerShell code, which SO and the like requires.

Comment: I've never seen a Vagrant topic, well, because, I've never known, Vagrant, as a product, service, the software even existed, thus no reason for me to look for it.  So, noi idea where to send you other than the Vagrant site itself. or the web in general ['vagrant powershell core linux'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27vagrant+powershell+core+linux%27&t=h_&ia=web). [hit(s)](https://blog.ipswitch.com/running-powershell-in-vagrant). If any of their solutions/cli, requires PowerShell, then you need to install PowerShell. THen ensure it's added to your sysmte path.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant is starting Windows executables from Linux. If the Linux is running under Windows host as a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL/WSL2) or as a Docker container, Vagrant will be looking for a PowerShell executable for Windows (.exe-file).

You can just add path to Powershell to your PATH environment variable under Linux. For example, if Windows drive `C:` on Linux is mounted as `/mnt/c`, add the following PATH variable.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0"
```

You can add the above line to your `~/.profile` file and reload it using the following commands:

```
nano ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

This way, Vagrant will be able to start.

Through the environment variable `VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS`, Vagrant understand that it may access the Windows system to run executable files and use functions such as synced folders. Thus, you may also need to add the following variable:

```
export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"
```

With this variable, Vagrant will start Windows executlable files from Linux, including the Windows `cmd.exe` command-line interpreter. Therefore, you should also need to add path to `cmd.exe`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32"
```

Otherwise, you will get the following error.

```
The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

And if you are using VirtualBox installed in Windows Host, you will also need to add the path to it:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox"
```

Since Linux under WSL is running within a virtual machine, you will not be able to run a hypervisor for Linux like VirtualBox what would have run under WSL. So Vagrant from Linux will be using VirtualBox installed on the Windows host.

Please make sure that you are using the latest version of Vagrant, or at least 2.2.15, otherwise it may not be able to run Windows executables from Linux properly. Anyway, running Vagrant from Linux to create virtual machines in Windows Virtualbox does not always run smoothly, you may get errors like that:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "a1d5c124-261b-4e4b-a11a-88f7bfdda6df", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to get device handle and/or partition ID for 
0000000001cf34e0 (hPartitionDevice=0000000000000a39, Last=0xc0000002/1) 
(VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

To avoid these errors, and make Vagrant to work reliably, just run Linux under physical hardware, not from WSL or a docker container under Windows. In this case, Virtualbox will also be running from Linux, and Vagrant will not need to communicate between Linux and Windows by running Windows executables on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I've never heard of Vagrant, yet a quick search of the Vagrant site, explains its PowerShell integration, use case. i.e.

> Command: vagrant powershell
>
> https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/powershell

```
# Command: 

vagrant powershell
<#
This will open a PowerShell prompt on the host into a running Vagrant guest machine.

This command will only work if the machines supports PowerShell. Not every environment will support PowerShell. At the moment, only Windows is supported with this command.
#>
```

See also:

[Running PowerShell In Vagrant](https://blog.ipswitch.com/running-powershell-in-vagrant)

[Create And Provision Your Local VM With Vagrant, Hyper-V and Docker-Machine](https://medium.com/@scott.rangeley/create-and-provision-your-local-vm-with-vagrant-hyper-v-and-docker-machine-d1acf0571256)

Comment: Just to be clear, I have no interest in running PowerShell in Vagrant or in Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu in Docker, and trying to add Vagrant, and I am getting this unexpected PowerShell message. That is why I had added the powershell category. I assume somewhere between Docker, Vagrant, and PowerShell, something is getting confused I have now deleted that label since you think it is misleading

Comment: I am not telling you to run X to Y, but if your tool of use requires the existence of specific resources, software, configuration, etc., then you must provide it. It is not PowerShell asking for this, it's your environment. I get the frustration, and what you are willing or not willing to do, but requirements are requirements. You really need to directly raise this with Vagrant and ask why this is being asked for; or of course, wait to see if anyone else is using what you are using and has a workaround. I did see you posted this to the Unbuntu forum as well.